# How do I fix the error cross-reference-class in texindy?

Tags: cross-referencing, indexing, imakeidx, xindy, makeindex

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\begin{filecontents*}{tmp.xdy}
(markup-index :open  "\begin{theindex}\rmfamily~n
\providecommand*\lettergroupDefault[1]{}
\providecommand*\lettergroup[1]{%
\par\centering\fbox{\textbf{#1}}\par\nopagebreak
}"
      :close "~n~n\end{theindex}~n"
      :tree)

(markup-indexentry :open "~n  \item "       :depth 0)
(markup-indexentry :open "~n  \subitem "    :depth 1)
(markup-indexentry :open "~n  \subsubitem " :depth 2)
( define-letter-group "Rakamlar"           :prefixes ("0" "1" "2" "3" "4" "6" "5" "7" "8" "9") :before "A")
( define-letter-group "Simgeler"           :prefixes ("\%") :before "Rakamlar")
(markup-crossref-list :class "bkz" :open "\bkz{" :sep "; " :close "}{}")
(markup-locclass-list :open "\dotfill " :sep ", ")
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[noautomatic,nonewpage]{imakeidx}
\makeindex[columns=2,title=\textit{Dizin}]
\newcommand{\bkz}[1]{\ (\emph{bkz.} #1) } %see only
\newcommand{\ayr}[1]{\ (\emph{A$\!$yr.} #1) } % also
\newcommand{\ayrbkz}[1]{\ (\emph{A$\!$yr.bkz.} #1) } % also see
\begin{document}

Page One
\index{şemsiye} \index{çatal} \index{tel} \index{73| \bkz{88}}
\newpage 
Page Two 
\index{73} \index{şemsiye} \index{\%50}
\newpage            
after many pages
\index{çatal}\index{kaşık| \ayr{çatal}} 
\newpage        
\index{şemsiye| \bkz{siyah}} \index{tel \ayrbkz{\textit{wire}}}      
\printindex
\end{document}
```

1) First `.pdf` image:

[image]

2) My console code: `texindy -C utf8 -L turkish -M tmp.xdy tmp.idx`

> ...
>
> WARNING: unknown cross-reference-class ` \bkz'! (ignored)
>
> WARNING: unknown cross-reference-class ` \ayr'! (ignored)
>
> WARNING: unknown cross-reference-class ` \bkz'! (ignored)
>
> ...

Second .pdf image:

[image]

3) But the output should be as follows but I could not. And I marked it red 
what i'm trying to do.

[image]

How can this bug fix? I made a lot of changes, but I didn't succeed.

**Note:** Since we could not access imgur site; The visuals I added can be a bit big. I apologize.